# Calculate difference between two dates excluding weekends in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I want to create function which return me the difference between two dates excluding weekends and holidays ?

Eg:- Difference between 01/07/2019 and 08/07/2019 should return me 5 days excluding (weekend on 6/7/107 and 7/07/2019).

What should be best possible way to achieve this ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try converting string into date using the format of your date using [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

use [`np.busday_count`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) to find difference between days excluding the weekends

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date1 = "01/07/2019"
date2 = "08/07/2019"

date1 = pd.to_datetime(date1,format="%d/%m/%Y").date()
date2 = pd.to_datetime(date2,format="%d/%m/%Y").date()

days = np.busday_count( date1 , date2)
print(days)
```

```
5
```

## incase you want to provide holidays

```
holidays = pd.to_datetime("04/07/2019",format="%d/%m/%Y").date()
days = np.busday_count( start, end,holidays=[holidays] )
print(days)
```

```
4
```

Comment: Thanks...it can exclude weekends but in case i have list of holidays as well like holidays=["04/07/2019"] ......now difference should be 4 days ....can i incorporate it within a function ???

Comment: ye can do that if you read documentation of np.busday_count there is a parameter of holidays where you can provide datetime list

Comment: you have to try that parameter

Comment: @ParasGhai I have updated the answer with holidays mask