# How to calculate difference between dates excluding weekends in Pyspark 2.2.0

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have the below pyspark df which can be recreated by the code

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "John Doe", "2020-11-30"),(2, "John Doe", "2020-11-27"),(3, "John Doe", "2020-11-29")],
                            ("id", "name", "date")) 

   +---+--------+----------+
| id|    name|      date|
+---+--------+----------+
|  1|John Doe|2020-11-30|
|  2|John Doe|2020-11-27|
|  3|John Doe|2020-11-29|
+---+--------+----------+
```

I am looking to create a udf to calculate difference between 2 rows of dates (using Lag function) excluding weekends as pyspark 2.2.0 does not has an in-built function to do so. eg. the difference between 2020-11-30 & 2020-11-27 should give 1 as they are Monday & Friday respectively.

I have tried to create the below with help from [calculate difference between two dates excluding weekends in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194543/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends-in-python) :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import numpy as np
workdaUDF = udf(lambda z: workdays(z),IntegerType())
def workdays():
date1 = df.select(F.col('date')).collect()[1][0]
date2 = df.select(F.col('date')).collect()[0][0]
date_diff = np.busday_count(date1,date2)
return date_diff

df.withColumn("date_dif",workdaysUDF(F.col("date"))).show(truncate=False)
```

But I get the below error

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Any help on how I can make this work on each row of my dataframe would be really helpful.

PS : My date1 and date2 variables need to be dynamic depending on the value of the date on which the function is being applied to. Also, due to the dataframe size, I cannot use pandas for which I found multiple solutions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `collect` in the UDF. You can only pass in columns to the UDF, so you should pass in the date column and the `lag` date column, as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "John Doe", "2020-11-30"),
    (2, "John Doe", "2020-11-27"),
    (3, "John Doe", "2020-11-29")],
    ("id", "name", "date")
) 

workdaysUDF = F.udf(lambda date1, date2: int(np.busday_count(date2, date1)) if (date1 is not None and date2 is not None) else None, IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn("date_dif", workdaysUDF(F.col('date'), F.lag(F.col('date')).over(Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy('id'))))
df.show()

+---+--------+----------+--------+
| id|    name|      date|date_dif|
+---+--------+----------+--------+
|  1|John Doe|2020-11-30|    null|
|  2|John Doe|2020-11-27|      -1|
|  3|John Doe|2020-11-29|       1|
+---+--------+----------+--------+
```